# WCF Transport Security Using Client Certificates

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, ssl, certificate

I've been working off the following URL's to try to accomplish WCF Transport Security using client certificates on my development machine (so my box is serving as the client and the server).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648498.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650751.aspx

My environment is Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7 with IIS 7.5. Everything seems to be fine up until the point I make a request to the server either by opening IE and browsing to one of my .svc files or running my Windows Form .NET client app and making a call to the service at which point I get the following error:

HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden

The page you are attempting to access requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client certificate that the Web server recognizes.

Server config file:

```
<bindings>
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CertificateWithTransport" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Client config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CertificateWithTransport" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="clientCertificateConf">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate
              findValue="32 52 dc 36 e1 95 fb be 4e 3c f6 a6 92 13 53 f4 b5 32 47 45"
              storeLocation="CurrentUser"
              storeName="My"
              x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
            </clientCredentials>
          <!--<clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="CN=localhostclient"
              storeLocation="CurrentUser"
              storeName="My"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          </clientCredentials>-->
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>  
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://localhost/Source.svc" behaviorConfiguration="clientCertificateConf"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransport"
        contract="SourceServerReference.ISourceService" name="SourceService.wsHttp" />
      <endpoint address="https://localhost/Community.svc" behaviorConfiguration="clientCertificateConf"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransport"
        contract="CommunityServerReference.ICommunityService" name="CommunityService.wsHttp" />
      <endpoint address="https://localhost/ActivityLeadContact.svc"
        behaviorConfiguration="clientCertificateConf" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransport" contract="ActivityLeadContactServerReference.IActivityLeadContactService"
        name="ActivityLeadContactService.wsHttp" />
      <endpoint address="https://localhost/User.svc" behaviorConfiguration="clientCertificateConf"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransport"
        contract="UserServerReference.IUserService" name="UserService.wsHttp" />
      <endpoint address="https://localhost/PickListItem.svc" behaviorConfiguration="clientCertificateConf"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransport"
        contract="PickListItemServerReference.IPickListItemService"
        name="PickListItemService.wsHttp" />
      <endpoint address="https://localhost/Prospect.svc" behaviorConfiguration="clientCertificateConf"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransport"
        contract="ProspectServiceReference.IProspectService" name="ProspectService.wsHttp" />
      <endpoint address="https://localhost/ActivityLead.svc" behaviorConfiguration="clientCertificateConf"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransport"
        contract="ActivityLeadServiceReference.IActivityLeadService"
        name="ActivityLeadService.wsHttp" />
      <endpoint address="https://localhost/ActivityReferral.svc" behaviorConfiguration="clientCertificateConf"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransport"
        contract="ActivityReferralServiceReference.IActivityReferralService"
        name="ActivityReferralService.wsHttp" />
      <endpoint address="https://localhost/Referral.svc" behaviorConfiguration="clientCertificateConf"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CertificateWithTransport"
        contract="ReferralServiceReference.IReferralService" name="ReferralService.wsHttp" />
      <endpoint address="https://localhost/LeadService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="clientCertificateConf"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LeadService.wsHttp"
        contract="LeadServerReference.ILeadService" name="LeadService.wsHttp" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The client certificate is probably not trusted. According to the links you mentioned the client certificate and server certificates are not selfsigned.

You should check if CA that issued a cert (client and server) is in local computer store. Also check if a CRL issued by CA (that issued client and CA that issued server certificate) is also placed in the local computer store and that it is valid (it has a validation period and after that you need to issue another CRL and place it in the store).

You can use mmc tool to check that.

p.s.: I would suggest that you use [xca](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) to issue certificates and CRLs. It has a GUI and you can set validation periods for certificates and CRLs so it is easy to issue a CRL for 100 years. It also has templates for CA, client and server certificates by default.